# Adding active class to element on menu

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I'm looking to add an active element class to my navbar, when I select the next link the previous one stays highlighted, I just want the current link to remain active.

See code below:

```
 <header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

    
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    alert(item.outerHTML);
    if(item.className === "active"){
    item.classList.remove("active");
    }
    item.classList.add("active");

  });

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9xca1pgh/42/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because the item in the event is target to this

itself, you need to find the active tag and remove it.

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    alert(item.outerHTML);
    document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => {
        if(item.className === "active"){
    item.classList.remove("active");
    }
    });
    item.classList.add("active");

  });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove active class from all `li` element and add the active class to the current one

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(i => {i.classList.remove('active')})
    item.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

If you want to use for loops

```js
for(let item of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // Remove active class from all li
    for(let i of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
      i.classList.remove('active')
    }
    item.classList.add('active')
  })
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do this with a for of loop instead?